# Is there a Gedit plugin that displays an overview map?

Tags: gedit, plugins, 21.04

Is there a Gedit plugin that shows an overview map of the current file at the right side to help scroll through the text?

I am using Gedit 3.38.1 in Ubuntu 21.04.

Here is an example of the overview map in VisualStudio Code. Does Gedit have something similar?

[image]